# Simple ios app example (UITabbarController, UITableView)

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller

I made app with three tab bars (thought IB) and it works.
But, in one view I need table view and when I click on row, to get detailes about this row.

There is some project example **how to do this programmatically** without using Interface builder?

Comment: Why do you want to do this without Interface Builder?

Comment: I want to learn how to code this by hand. I don't understand what IB is doing for me, and a lot of tutorials are for xCode 3, and in xCode 4 is the whole IB different. A lot of reasons :)

Comment: OK, learning is certainly good. But in the long term I encourage you to use IB. It will make things a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

To create an UITableView programmatically:

```
UITableView *myTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,420)];
myTable.dataSource = self;
myTable.delegate = self;
```

Then implement the [UITableViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) and [UITableViewDataSource](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) methods as you would have done when using InterfaceBuilder.

For selecting the row create the delegate function

```
– tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:
```

and push a new UIView onto the nagivationController. Alternatively (if you don't use a navigationController), you can also present the new view as a modalViewController.

Comment: Yea, but I need some sample app with implemented something like this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LBnPfAtswgw but programmatically

Comment: In that case I recommend this book: http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_i_0_30?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=beginning+iphone+4+development&x=0&y=0&sprefix=beginning+iphone+4+development

Answer (score 1):

Check out the material for the Stanford iPhone programming classes. They have some great TableView sections that include samples for building these in code. See [the course website](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p).